# how to prevent multiple selection of radio button in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I'm using radio button in my ASP.net project, my problem is that I can't prevent the multiple selection.I want to select only one item.
this is my code :

```
 @for (int k = 0; k < players.Count();k++)
                {
                    String kk = Convert.ToString(k);
                <li class="first">           
                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => players[k].ID_player)
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem => players[k].SelectedPlayer,
                players[k].ID_player , new { @id = kk })                    
                <a href="#">@players[k].first_name_player @Html.Raw(" ")
                @players[k].second_name_player</a>
                </li>   
                }
```

any help please.

Comment: new { id = kk } should be new { @id = kk, Name = "grp" }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new { @id = kk }` should be `new { @id = kk, Name = "grp" }` to prevent multiple selection of Radio Button.